# PHP compare 2 arrays (Mac donalds and Burger King)

Tags: php, html, checkbox, sum, comparison

I have to make a comparison site for the products from MC and BK.

http://informaticaphp.net84.net/home.php <- that's how far I am.

This is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
</head>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
    {
        $breakfastMC = $_POST['BreakfastMC'];
        $breakfastBK = $_POST['BreakfastBK'];

        if(empty($breakfastMC)) 
        {
            echo("<p>You didn't select any food.</p>\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $MC = count($breakfastMC);

            echo("<p>You selected $MC: ");
            for($i=0; $i < $MC; $i++)
            {
                echo($breakfastMC[$i] . " ");
            }

        }
        if(empty($breakfastBK)) 
        {
            echo("<p>You didn't select any food.</p>\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $BK = count($breakfastBK);

            echo("<p>You selected $BK door(s): ");
            for($i=0; $i < $BK; $i++)
            {
                echo($breakfastBK[$i] . " ");
            }
        }
//$sumBK = array_sum($BK)       
//$sumMC = array_sum($MC)
if ($sumBK = $sumMC){
echo 'equal';
}

    function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
    {
        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
        {
            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
            {
                if($chkval == $value)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<div class="MC">
<h2><b>Mc Donalds</b></h2>
<br />
<b>Ontbijt:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="2">  Croissant met jam en boter<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="3">  Pancakes met stroop <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="3">  McMuffin met Bacon en Ei <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="4">  McMuffin met Kaas <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC1"   value="2">  2x Versgemalen koffie <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC2"   value="2">  2x Thee <br />

<b>Lunch:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC1"   value="LunchMD1">  Hamburger <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC2"   value="LunchMD2">  Cheeseburger <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC3"   value="LunchMD3">  1955 met bacon <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC4"   value="LunchMD4">  McKroket <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC3"   value="DrinksMD3">  Coca Cola Middel (0,4L) <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC4"   value="DrinksMD4">  Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br />

<b>Avondeten:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC1"   value="DinerMD1">  Big Mac <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC2"   value="DinerMD2">  Chicken Sensation <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC3"   value="DinerMD3">  Chili Chicken <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC4"   value="DinerMD4">  Big Tasty met bacon <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC5"   value="DrinkeMD5">  Coca Cola Mega (0,7L) <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC6"   value="DrinksMD6">  Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br />

<br />

</div>

<div class="BK">

<h2><b>Burger King </b></h2>

<b>Ontbijt:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3">  Mini Pancakes (9stuks) €1,50 364kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="1.50">  Toastie €1,50 359 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3.00">  Breakfast Burger €3,00  825 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.75">  Breakfast Wrap €2,75 441 kcal<br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK1"   value="3.80">  2xKoffie €3,80 0 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK2"   value="2.25">  1 flesje Chaudfontaine (500 ml) €2,25 0 kcal<br />

<b>Lunch:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK1"   value="4.55">  Grilled Chicken Wrap €4,55  344 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK2"   value="1.95">  Cheeseburger €1,95 338 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK3"   value="5.75">  Tripple Whopper €5,75  1114 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK4"   value="4.75">  Big King XXL  €4,75 1022 kcal<br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK3"   value="2.00">  Coca Cola M (400 ml)  €2,00 168 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK4"   value="2.50">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

<b>Avondeten:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK1"   value="DinerBK1">  Double Cheeseburger XXL  €4,75  502 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK2"   value="DinerBK2">  Grilled Chicken BBQ €5,25 707 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK3"   value="DinerBK3">  Whopper Jr. €3,25 362 kcal  <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK4"   value="DinerBK4">  Big King €3,75 552 kcal <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK5"   value="DrinksBK5">  Coca Cola M (400 ml) €2,25 210 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK6"   value="DrinksBK6">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

</div>
<div class="Button">
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit">
</div>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now what I want is to make a total sum of all the values checked within the area and then compare the pricedifference from the BK and the MC

this:

```
//$sumBK = array_sum($BK)       
//$sumMC = array_sum($MC)
if ($sumBK = $sumMC){
echo 'equal';
```

Doesn't work so I am kinda clueless :(

Comment: Firstly: `if ($sumBK = $sumMC)` should be `if ($sumBK == $sumMC)`

Comment: yes little typemistake there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the necessary changes to your code to make it work and do what I think you want. Here it is, the changes are pointed by commented arrows "// <=======", try it and let me know :

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />

</head>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
    {
        $breakfastMC = $_POST['BreakfastMC'];
        $breakfastBK = $_POST['BreakfastBK'];
        $sumMC = 0; // <================================================================
        $sumBK = 0; // <================================================================
        if(empty($breakfastMC)) 
        {
            echo("<p>You didn't select any food in MC.</p>\n"); // <=========
        } 
        else 
        {
            $MC = count($breakfastMC);

            echo("<p>You selected for MC = $MC:<br/>"); // <=========
            for($i=0; $i < $MC; $i++)
            {   
                echo( "Price = " . $breakfastMC[$i] . "<br/>"); // <====================
                $sumMC += floatval( $breakfastMC[$i] ); // <============================
            }
            echo "Total MC = " . $sumMC . "<br/>"; // <====================================
        }
        if(empty($breakfastBK)) 
        {
            echo("<p>You didn't select any food in BK.</p>\n"); // <====================
        } 
        else 
        {
            $BK = count($breakfastBK);

            echo("<p>You selected for BK = $BK:<br/>"); // <============================
            for($i=0; $i < $BK; $i++)
            {
                echo( "Price = " . $breakfastBK[$i] . "<br/>"); // <====================
                $sumBK += floatval( $breakfastBK[$i] ); // <============================
            }
            echo "Total BK = " . $sumBK . "<br/>"; // <====================================
        }
//$sumBK = array_sum($BK)       
//$sumMC = array_sum($MC)
if ( $sumBK == $sumMC )  // <===========================================================
    echo 'equal'; // <==================================================================
else if ( $sumBK > $sumMC )  // <=======================================================
          echo 'BK more expensive than MC'; // <========================================
     else echo 'MC more expensive than BK'; // <========================================


    function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
    {
        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
        {
            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
            {
                if($chkval == $value)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<div class="MC">
<h2><b>Mc Donalds</b></h2>
<br />
<b>Ontbijt:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="2">  Croissant met jam en boter<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="3">  Pancakes met stroop <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="3">  McMuffin met Bacon en Ei <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastMC[]"   value="4">  McMuffin met Kaas <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC1"   value="2">  2x Versgemalen koffie <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC2"   value="2">  2x Thee <br />

<b>Lunch:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC1"   value="LunchMD1">  Hamburger <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC2"   value="LunchMD2">  Cheeseburger <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC3"   value="LunchMD3">  1955 met bacon <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchMC4"   value="LunchMD4">  McKroket <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC3"   value="DrinksMD3">  Coca Cola Middel (0,4L) <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC4"   value="DrinksMD4">  Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br />

<b>Avondeten:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC1"   value="DinerMD1">  Big Mac <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC2"   value="DinerMD2">  Chicken Sensation <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC3"   value="DinerMD3">  Chili Chicken <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerMC4"   value="DinerMD4">  Big Tasty met bacon <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC5"   value="DrinkeMD5">  Coca Cola Mega (0,7L) <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksMC6"   value="DrinksMD6">  Coca Cola Groot (0,5L) <br />

<br />

</div>

<div class="BK">

<h2><b>Burger King </b></h2>

<b>Ontbijt:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3">  Mini Pancakes (9stuks) €1,50 364kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="1.50">  Toastie €1,50 359 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="3.00">  Breakfast Burger €3,00  825 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="BreakfastBK[]"   value="2.75">  Breakfast Wrap €2,75 441 kcal<br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK1"   value="3.80">  2xKoffie €3,80 0 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK2"   value="2.25">  1 flesje Chaudfontaine (500 ml) €2,25 0 kcal<br />

<b>Lunch:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK1"   value="4.55">  Grilled Chicken Wrap €4,55  344 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK2"   value="1.95">  Cheeseburger €1,95 338 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK3"   value="5.75">  Tripple Whopper €5,75  1114 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="LunchBK4"   value="4.75">  Big King XXL  €4,75 1022 kcal<br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK3"   value="2.00">  Coca Cola M (400 ml)  €2,00 168 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK4"   value="2.50">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

<b>Avondeten:</b>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK1"   value="DinerBK1">  Double Cheeseburger XXL  €4,75  502 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK2"   value="DinerBK2">  Grilled Chicken BBQ €5,25 707 kcal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK3"   value="DinerBK3">  Whopper Jr. €3,25 362 kcal  <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DinerBK4"   value="DinerBK4">  Big King €3,75 552 kcal <br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK5"   value="DrinksBK5">  Coca Cola M (400 ml) €2,25 210 kcal <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="DrinksBK6"   value="DrinksBK6">  Coca Cola XXL (750 ml) €2,50  315 kcal<br />

</div>
<div class="Button">
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="submit">
</div>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You were very close to your goal. First of all, the total variables "sumMC" and "sumBK" are initalized since the beginning and used in the "for" statements, and the use of "< br/ >" improves the visual.

Answer (score 0):

By doing:

```
if ($sumBK = $sumMC){
    echo 'equal';
}
```

You are assigning `$sumMC`'s value to `$sumBK`, not comparing values. Use this instead and your code should work:

```
if ($sumBK === $sumMC){
    echo 'equal';
}
```

Comment: A little typemistake there, but this isn't the problem it just doesn't recognize the $breakfastMC = $_POST['BreakfastMC']; as an array.

Comment: Oh well, that was not very clear on your question. Try to use this to get the type of $breakfastMC so we can try to understand what's happening: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: Thanks for the link but I still don't really get it. Look uhm the idea is that people can tick the boxes for macdonalds and burgerking and when you click submit it sums up all the values from the boxes you checked and then checks which one is cheaper but I don't have a clue how to do that so this code won't work.

Comment: the gettype stuff, tells me it's NULL

Comment: Good, so we're getting somewhere. Unfortunately I can't keep helping you here in the comments because it would be considered flood. I tried to find you in the chat list so we can discuss there but couldn't find you for some reason.